# Using model.eval() on neural network results in same output everytime for very different inputs

Tags: python, machine-learning, testing, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a simple network implemented in pytorch say,

```
class network:

    def __init__(self):

        self.device = device
        #these are the 3 convolutional synapses; Same convolution;
        self.layer     = sequential(
                                conv2d(3, 3, (23), padding=11),
                                batch_norm_2d(3),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(3, 3, (11), padding=5),
                                batch_norm_2d(3),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(3, 3, (5), padding=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(3),
                                Swish(),

                                conv2d(3, 4, (3), padding=15, stride=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(4),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(4, 8, (3), padding=15, stride=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(8),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(8, 4, (1)),
                                batch_norm_2d(4),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(4, 8, (3), padding=15, stride=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(8),
                                Swish(),
                        
                                conv2d(8, 16, (3), padding=15, stride=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(16),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(16, 8, (1)),
                                batch_norm_2d(8),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(8, 16, (3), padding=15, stride=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(16),
                                Swish(),
                        
                                conv2d(16, 32, (3), padding=15, stride=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(32),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(32, 16, (1)),
                                batch_norm_2d(16),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(16, 32, (3), padding=15, stride=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(32),
                                Swish(),
                        
                                conv2d(32, 64, (3), padding=15, stride=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(64),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(64, 32, (1)),
                                batch_norm_2d(32),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(32, 64, (3), padding=15, stride=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(64),
                                Swish(),
                        
                                conv2d(64, 128, (3), padding=15, stride=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(128),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(128, 64, (1)),
                                batch_norm_2d(64),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(64, 128, (3), padding=15, stride=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(128),
                                Swish(),
                        
                                conv2d(128, 256, (3), padding=15, stride=2),
                                batch_norm_2d(256),
                                Swish(),
        
                                conv2d(256, 128, (1)),
                                batch_norm_2d(128),
                                Swish(),
                                
                                flatten(1, -1),
        
                                linear(128*29*29, 8*8*2*5),
                                batch_norm_1d(8*8*2*5),
                                Swish()
            )
    
    
        #loss and optimizer functions for ethirun
        self.Loss_1 = IoU_Loss() #the loss function for bounding box.
        self.Loss_2 = tor.nn.SmoothL1Loss(reduction='mean')
    
        #the optimizer
        self.Optimizer =     tor.optim.AdamW(self.parameters())#tor.optim.SGD(self.parameters(), lr=1e-2, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=1e-5, nesterov=True)
        self.Scheduler = tor.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(self.Optimizer, 288, gamma=0.5)
        self.sizes = tor.tensor(range(0, 5), dtype=tor.int64, device=self.device)

    def forward(self, input):
         return self.layer(input)

    def backprop(self, preds, lbls, val_or_trn):
    #takes predictions and labels and calculates error and backpropagates        
         mask = tor.index_select(lbls, -1, self.sizes[0])
         preds.register_hook(lambda grad: grad * mask.float())
         error = self.Loss_2(preds, lbls)
        
         if val_or_trn == 1:
             #backpropagation
             error.backward()
             self.Optimizer.step()
             self.Scheduler.step()
        
             #zeroing the gradients.
             self.Optimizer.zero_grad()
    

        return error.detach()

model = network()
```

Where the inputs, outputs and channels are arbitrary. Then say I create some random input tensor like this,

`input_data = torch.randn(1, 3, 256, 256)`

Then I predict some result in this data like this,

`model(input_data)`

And say I also change the *input_data* variable by initiating the *torch.randn* command a bunch of different times while keeping the model same. That is not re-initiating the *model=network()* command.

I get this error,

**Expected more than 1 value per channel when training, got input size torch.Size([1, some_value])**

So, I tried running it in evaluation mode by using the *model.eval()* function like this,

```
model.eval()

with tor.no_grad()
   pred = model(input_data)

model.train()
```

This works without errors. However no matter how I change the *input_data* variable I always get the same value in *pred*. If I however re-initiate the model's parameters I get a new *pred* Which once again does not change with different inputs. Unless I once again re-initiate the model using *model=network()*. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: To give more info on my problem I'm trying to create a yolo like network from scratch. And this is the dataset I'm using https://www.kaggle.com/devdgohil/the-oxfordiiit-pet-dataset

Comment: Make it more reproducible since I tried what you roughly gave, it worked without problem.

Comment: 1. What kind of activation you're using? I tried ReLu and see no problem here.

Comment: 2. That "something_here". It's not that difficult to write the usable value, in this case it's 254*254*3. A lot of people who may know what's the problem may just said "screw this" and went to another question.

Comment: 3. Are `conv2d` and `batch_norm_2d` the default in Pytorch? If you use something else then write them. If not then write what you use.

Comment: 1. I use a custom activation which is (x * torch.tanh(torch.nn.Softplus(x))) where x is the input.

Comment: 2. I should have done that. I'm sorry will correct it when asking questions next time.

Comment: 3. Yes, conv2d is torch.nn.Conv2d, batch_norm_2d is torch.nn.BatchNorm2d and batch_norm_1d is torch.nn.BatchNorm1d linear layer being torch.nn.Linear. I use these and they are default in pytorch.

Comment: The after posting this question I went back and tried a few things. If I run the code on a batch, with model in eval() mode the different predictions for each image in the batch are not exactly equal but almost equal. By that I mean for randomly generated images, a lot of the resulting predictions are same (I evaluated this with == sign between different predictions in the same batch which shows True or False for each item in the predictions individually). However doing the same with when the model is in training mode results in none of the predictions being same.

Comment: I'm actually making a yolo from scratch project. Which needs variation in its prediction for different input images. Also, after searching a bit I found this discussion https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/performance-highly-degraded-when-eval-is-activated-in-the-test-phase/3323  and here https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/model-eval-gives-incorrect-loss-for-model-with-batchnorm-layers/7561 I don't really want to implement the solutions given there. As I believe there might be a better way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks for being patient. And taking the time to figure this out.

Comment: You really need to provide the code that if I run it'll give the result you said. Since even with activation you said I can get different result by changing input

Comment: From what I can see, the smaller the `batchsize` the more similar the results in `train` model but I never get identical results both in `train` and `eval`.

Comment: Should I make a github repository with the code and share the link here?

Comment: I am using a *batch size* of *16*. And yes, that difference is what I am concerned about. Is there any way I can make there be no difference between the *train* and *eval*? without entirely removing batch norm that is.

Comment: Github is OK, but if the code is just one file edit your post is better

Comment: I'm afraid it might affect the accuracy of my model during testing it.

Comment: For the question. Basically that's what the Batchnorm doing. You use Batchnorm to make training less prone to overfit but don't use batchnorm in eval so that you can get the correct result

Comment: Same go for Dropout.

Comment: Every CNN model with batch normalization and/or dropout does the same. The output of the same input will be different during train and eval

Comment: Which is exactly why Pytorch has the `model.eval()`.

Comment: Oh. So I shouldn't use batch norm during testing? Thank you very much. That clears it up. I did not know that. If you post that I will mark it as an answer.

Comment: Call `model.eval` and it won't use batch norm

Comment: It's fine to keep them in the code. The `model.eval` is specifically made to disable batch normalization and dropout along with a lot of layers that change the result during inference.

Comment: So this means this question is answered? I'll post it answer section then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically that's what the Batchnorm doing. You use Batchnorm to make training less prone to overfit but don't use batchnorm in eval so that you can get the correct result Same go for Dropout.

Every CNN model with batch normalization and/or dropout does the same. The output of the same input will be different during train and eval

Which is exactly why Pytorch has the `model.eval()`. To turn these layers off during inference to get the correct output.

## Edit

The problem is the activation and Batch Normalization at the output.

Only use something that will make the result similar to the ground truth. Like use `sigmoid` when you want output to be in range of 0-1 or `tanh` for -1 to 1 or `softmax` for probability across the axis.

Imagine `relu` function (which is basically the simpler version of `swish` and `softplus`). It will turn everything below 0 to 0. And chances are you need some output to be below 0 so your model won't converge at all.

Comment: Hey so I think I made a mistake. I get calling **eval** turns batchnorm and dropout off. (I am not using dropout) problem is that the predictions made by the model in **eval** are almost consistent across all of the images in the validation set. It looks like it is taking a average guess of where a dog's or cat's face could appear in a image. Instead of telling me exactly where the face is in a given image. The output is stuck in **eval** mode. That is where my problem is. I will now update the question with my exact model.

Comment: I updated the question with my exact model. Can you see a problem?

Comment: You use both `swish` and `batch_norm` in the last layer? Why?

Comment: IIRC yolo need a part of the output to be `sigmoid` for bounding box. Other part to be `softmax` for classification

Comment: And batch normalizing the output is a very bad idea

Comment: Oh. I was actually using the (x * tor.tanh(softplus(x))) before I replaced it with swish. I will remove the batch norm from the output layer and will let you know the results. Won't using swish for the output work? As technically it is derived from sigmoid. For now I'm not doing any kind of classification. I'm just doing bounding box prediction and am predicting the confidence metric for each of the bounding box in order to use n-max suppression on them and filter only relevant bounding boxes.

Comment: No you shouldn't use "activation" function in the output

Comment: Only use something that will make the result similar to the ground truth. Like use `sigmoid` when you want output to be in range of 0-1 or `tanh` for -1 to 1 or `softmax` for probability across the axis.

Comment: Imagine `relu` function (which is basically the simpler version of `swish` and `softplus`). It will turn everything below 0 to 0. And chances are you need some output to be below 0 so your model won't converge at all.

Comment: Now the `x * torch.tanh(softplus(x))`. If I'm imaging things correctly this will make the positive result very small and turn big negative result to 0. So if you put another `sigmoid` here (you need to calculate the bounding boxes) it won't go below 0.5.

Comment: Oh my god. It works. The model's **eval()** function no longer seems to predict bad, rigid bounding boxes for any and all input images I give. As the training epochs increase calling the **eval()** function now instead produces sensible and very good predictions. Thank you very very much please post the don't use activation and batch norm in the output part as an answer. I don't really understand why this happens. But that using them in the output layer was making almost all of models obselete.

Answer (score 0):

You defined a neural network, but you are not **training it**.

For your model to predict different outputs from a same input after several iterations over data, your model needs to be able to tweak its weights and biases.

To do so, you need a loss function and optimizer, from which you'll be able to backpropagates the prediction error to adjust the model’s parameters, via gradient descent.

I invite you to follow that link, where every step to train a model in PyTorch are covered: [QuickStart PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/quickstart_tutorial.html#optimizing-the-model-parameters)

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I was not clear. I don't want to predict multiple outputs from same input. Rather my problem is that whatever Input, however random it is is given to the network with training or without training, the model if in evaluation mode gives me the same output. Which is what I am unable to understand why.